# Gambler's Ruin: Win 2 dollars, Lose 1 dollar

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

An individual has 50 dollars and is gambling on a series of coin flips. A head results in a win of 2 dollars and a tail results in a loss of 1 dollar. What’s the probability that the person will run out of money?

This is a Gambler's Ruin/Random Walk problem. However I'm not sure how to set up this variation.

I know that the probability of starting at i dollars and reaching a value of N dollars based on a 1 dollar win/loss fair game is:

$P_1 = \frac{i}{N}$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any restriction on the length of the series?

Comment: No, this is the only information provided. Usually with these problems there is a "win" at $100 or some other value. This problem just continues forever unless you lose.

Comment: @user:  If the bet is in your favor, as here, it is reasonable to ask the chance the player can go on forever given an initial stake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define $P(n)$ as the chance that he eventually runs out of money if he starts with $n$.The recurrence is $$P(n)=\frac 12P(n-1)+\frac 12P(n+2)\\P(0)=1$$  We can rewrite the recurrence as $P(n+2)=2P(n)-P(n-1)$.  The characteristic equation is $x^3=2x-1$ with roots $1, \frac 12(\sqrt 5-1), \frac 12(-1-\sqrt 5)$ or $1,\phi-1,-\phi$.

The general solution is $P(n)=a1^n+b(\phi-1)^n+c(-\phi)^n$ with $a+b+c=1$ to match the condition $P(0)=1.$  $c$ must be $0$.  If $c \gt 0$ the probability will be negative for large odd $n$ and greater than $1$ for large even $n$.  If $c \lt 0$ the same will be true reversing odd and even.  If he starts with a lot of money the chance of going broke becomes small, so $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(n)=0$, which tells us that the coefficient on $1^n$ is zero.  We get $$P(n)=(\phi-1)^n$$
and in particular if he starts with just one dollar he has about $0.382$ chance of playing forever.

Comment: Very nice solution! But what do you mean with "large odd n of one parity"?

Comment: @user:  if $c \gt 0$ then with $n$ large and odd that term will be large and negative.  If $c \lt 0$ then it is with $n$ large and even that the term is large and negative.  For the other parity the probability will get greater than $1$ for large $n$.  I clarified it.

Comment: I meant that one of the words "odd" and "of one parity" is probably excessive. In any case for large enough $n$ the absolute value of expression would exceed 1 what is impossible.

Comment: @RossMillikan, where is p(n+1) / why would it be missing from this equation?

Comment: @jbuddy_13:  it isn't there because in one roll he can't go from $n$ to $n+1$.  He either wins and goes to $n+2$ or loses and goes to $n-1$

Comment: Oh I see, $n+x$ represents the future state where $x$ is the respective win or loss.